# Get array of dates between two dates with custom interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this data:

```
const start = "29.09.2021";
const end = "29.10.2021";
const interval = "days"; //also: "month", "week", "year"
const intervalCount = 3;
```

how to get an array of dates that exists between `start` and `end` with intervals: eq. if interval == "days" and intervalCount == 3 then another dates should be 02.10, 05.10, 08.10, 11.10 etc., but interval can be also "month", "week", and "year" so I must calculate based on the dynamic arguments

I have no idea how to even start, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Date objects found here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

You can create a function such as

```
function getDates(startDateString, stopDateString, interval){
  var dates = [];
  var start = new Date(startDateString);
  var stop = new Date(stopDateString);

  while (start < stop) {
    dates.push (start.toJSON());
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + interval);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

And then you can run the function by making this call

```
dateArray = getDates("09-29-2021", "10-29-2021", 1)
```

It covers single day iterations. A week is just a 7 day interval.

```
dateArray = getDates("09-29-2021", "10-29-2021", 7)
```

Moving months gets into edge cases that can be handled through conditions based on your use case (For example, if the date is Jan 31st, should a jump of 1 month take you to Mar 3rd or Feb 28th/29th?)